# Current Transformer - example (basic) circuit request

Tags: current-measurement, breadboard

I'm trying to setup an XBee to monitor power usage of a device. At the moment, I'm trying to get a basic circuit setup on a breadboard, without the XBee.

I have purchased a https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11005 Current Transformer to use. Can anyone provide me with a basic circuit to utilise the CT? I'll eventually be feeding it with a 3.3v regulated supply that the XBee requires, but I'm currently using a 5V power supply with the breadboard.

Comment: It sounds like you are planning to measure (or test with) Direct Current - current transformers only work with Alternating Current - DC won't produce any output.

Answer (score 3):

See [data sheet here](http://dlnmh9ip6v2uc.cloudfront.net/datasheets/Sensors/Current/ECS1030-L72-SPEC.pdf)

[image]

See page 2 of the data sheet - connect 10 Ohms across the output terminals.
Vout with 10 Ohms connected is ~= 5 mV/Amp -  as per graph.

**WARNING** -  NEVER operate a CT with no load across the output.
Death of the CT and of anything connected to the output is likely.

Comment: And if anyone wants to know *why*, multiply 50uA (from the CT) by 5Mohm (CMOS input resistance).